# Generate laravel models from tables

Tags: laravel, model, generator

I'm new to Laravel but have worked on Hibernate with Java.

Is there a way to generate models from existing tables?

All I found is creating migrations to create tables.

Answer (score 0):

[The Larry Four package](https://github.com/XCMer/larry-four-generator) will allow you to do so, but please note that I have not used it myself.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15247572)

Comment: Well, you're not wrong, @DonaldDuck, but you do realise the answer is over two years old and does not contain a link to any actual code?